# Hiding separator lines and top border line in iOS Charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have a generated chart. I'm trying to make it as simple as possible, thus removing all the unneeded lines, grids, labels etc. I can't get rid of the separator line between the bars and the top and right border lines, as you can see on the picture. I'm using HorizontalBarChart.

[image]

Also, here you can see my chart setup code, I tried to disable literally everything:

```
private func setupCharts(selectedHero: Int) {
    classWinrateChart.descriptionText = ""
    classWinrateChart.legend.enabled = false
    classWinrateChart.drawBordersEnabled = false
    classWinrateChart.drawMarkers = false
    classWinrateChart.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataSource, label: "Noaaah")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""], dataSet: chartDataSet)
    let color = constants.colors[selectedHero]
    chartDataSet.colors = [color]
    chartDataSet.valueFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)
    //chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false

    let yAxis = classWinrateChart.leftAxis
    let xAxis = classWinrateChart.rightAxis

    yAxis.enabled = false
    yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    yAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    yAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    xAxis.enabled = false
    xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    classWinrateChart.rightAxis.enabled = false

    yAxis.axisMaxValue = 100
    yAxis.axisMinValue = 0

    classWinrateChart.tintColor = colors[selectedHero]

    classWinrateChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    classWinrateChart.data = chartData
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help you :

```
    var viwBar = BarChartView()

    viwBar.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    viwBar.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    viwBar.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    viwBar.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false

     //removes left and right axis representation
    let yaxis = viwBar.getAxis(ChartYAxis.AxisDependency.Left)
    yaxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    yaxis.enabled = false

    let xaxis = viwBar.getAxis(ChartYAxis.AxisDependency.Right)
    xaxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    xaxis.enabled = false
```

Comment: Thanks to you, this answer should be accepted as well. Can I have one more help? I can't disable leftAxis as shown in this fig (https://puu.sh/vYVW5/78722a9414.png). And when i applied you code, it hide also the yaxis label and it separator. I don't want to hide the label, I just want to hide separator and give some spacing. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

check your code, Is it like ?
`let xAxis = classWinrateChart.rightAxis`

`classWinrateChart.rightAxis` is `rightAxis`, not `xAxis`.